# How to get Ubuntu Gnome to suspend after 5 minutes

Tags: gnome, suspend

I have recently installed Ubuntu Gnome, and found that unlike in Unity, in the Gnome Shell I am unable to tell my machine to suspended any sooner than 15 minutes, however for security reasons I want it to suspend after 5 minutes of inactivity. So as there is no built-in option to do this, how can this be achieved? Or would I need to file a bug report about this?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The command line way

- **On AC**

  - Sleep timeout computer when on AC

    `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout <time_in_seconds>`

    `0 = off`

    eg after 300 second:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 300
    ```
  - Whether to hibernate, suspend or do nothing when inactive

    `sleep-inactive-ac-type <hibernate|suspend|nothing>`

    eg suspend:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type suspend
    ```
- **On Battery**

  - Sleep timeout computer when on battery

    `sleep-inactive-battery-timeout <time_in_seconds>`

    `0 = off`

    *eg after 300 second:*

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 300
    ```
  - Whether to hibernate, suspend or do nothing when inactive

    `sleep-inactive-battery-type <hibernate|suspend|nothing>`

    eg suspend:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type suspend
    ```

---

### The GUI way

Start `dconf-editor` and open the schema `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`

[image]